# Linux: Convert CENTOS 5.x to Scientific Linux 6 (SL)

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

Scientific Linux 6.0 aims to be 100% based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux RHEL6.

Is there any possible way to **convert CENTOS 5.x to Scientific Linux 6** by console ?

i'm pretty sure, that centos 6 will not be released until 2035...

- http://www.scientificlinux.org/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversions like that are generally more trouble than it's worth. You will probably be better off just wiping `/usr` etc. and re-installing from scratch. Hopefully your `/home` is on a separate partition (in a well-done install it would be), then you won't have to wipe your personal settings and data. Of course, you should back them up as a precaution.

BTW, Gentoo Linux is also built from source and also has all the latest software listed there.